# NPM scripts permission denied on chronos (chromebook shell)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, chromebook

I recently installed node on my chromebook. I have git cloned a basic node repo that is trying to run things like webpack, babel-node, and concurrently through npm scripts.

However, running webpack (in the same directory) works just fine.

I have run "`sudo chmod -R 777 my_app`" and it did not help.

**Here is the error message:**

```
chronos@localhost ~/Downloads/MODULE $ npm start

> my-glitch-app@0.0.1 start /home/chronos/user/Downloads/MODULE
> concurrently "webpack -w -p" "babel-node server.js"

sh: concurrently: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 3.18.0-14875-g438cb8ab27c6
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-glitch-app@0.0.1 start: `concurrently "webpack -w -p" "babel-node server.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-glitch-app@0.0.1 start script 'concurrently "webpack -w -p" "babel-node server.js"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-glitch-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "webpack -w -p" "babel-node server.js"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-glitch-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-glitch-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/chronos/user/Downloads/MODULE/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Who's the owner of the files (`ls -l`)? You might need to `chown` it to your user.

Comment: I did whoami and it says "chronos" and each file says something like "drwxr-xr-x.   3 chronos chronos  4096 Sep 26 20:42 file/folderName"

Comment: Could you include the actual error in the original question?

Comment: @Svenskunganka I've added the error message

Comment: Thank you. The issue is most likely with the `concurrently` tool, which you should be able to find in `node_modules/.bin/concurrently`. Check its ownership and file permissions. If you've installed the package globally (`npm install -g` or `npm install --global`), it will be under the `bin` directory of wherever you've configured npm to store globally installed packages.

Comment: @Svenskunganka I checked and I have ownership and full permissions for those files.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it's clearly related to the mounted state of /home/chronos/user, under which this Downloads folder is found on Chrome OS. I've given up once and been using /usr/local/src, but i'm giving another shot now

Answer (score 0):

following my comment above, `sudo mount -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user` seemed to work, but i have further anomalies in my case, so i'd be curious about peer experience

Comment: Have you had any luck getting this to work? I can´t even install packages, get permission denied issues the whole time.

Comment: @JanPeeter I'm not using this project i had issues with anymore, but i use node regularly. npm install denying permission sounds like you installed node in a restricted directory, or using it in one. I've taken up the habit of storing my built binaries separately which i just add to the $PATH.

Comment: Managed to get it working. Was not using the chromeos mnt anymore then everything was good